# Hacer un LIKE para extraer datos que empiecen con 2 numeros

Tags: sql

Estoy realizando una consulta para traer una cierta columna que no es relevante en esto pero la quiero extraer bajo el criterio de otra columna numérica que es traer solo las que empiezan con 5 y 6 (los datos son por ejemplo: 500001, 22343, 600432), se me habia ocurrido algo como :

`CUENTA LIKE '[5-6%]'`

Esto no funciona y no he podido encontrar una sentencia que me ayude para esto.

Comment: `SELECT ...... WHERE ...... AND (CUENTA LIKE '5%' OR CUENTA LIKE '6%')`

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me resultó, la verdad me compliqué solo jaja

Comment: Tu idea también es válida, porque estarías usando una expresión regular. En tu caso sería `CUENTA LIKE '[5-6]%'`. (% afuera de la expresión) Te dejo algo de documentación https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sql-contains-string-sql-regex-example-query/

Comment: @javdromero siempre y cuando, su db lo acepte, cosa que no sabemos...

Comment: Correcto, lo del regex funciona en el caso de SQL Server, @SaulElizaldeCarrera edita la pregunta y agrega tu dbms a los tags para tener todo el contexto.